# Displaying wrong answers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a spelling game where the user spells the word by clicking on letters. To show the user how many they have wrong and right I count the amount of times the right and wrong message is displayed and print it to the user.

This works perfectly for correct answers but not for wrong answers. Can someone tell me why?

This is the script for the correct answers (works fine)...

```
var completeLetters = $('.wordglow2').length;
var completeWords = (completeLetters / 3);

    if ($(right).show()) {
        $('.counter').html("Right Answers = " + completeWords).show();
    }
```

Here is the one for incorrect answers (exactly the same logic, but won't work!)...

```
var incompleteLetters = $('.wordglow4').length;
var incompleteWords = (incompleteLetters / 3);

    if ($(wrong).show()) {
        $('.counter2').html("Wrong Answers = " + incompleteWords).show();
    }
```

So basically "wordglow4" is the style added to the letter when it is incorrectly spelt and "wordglow2" is the style added to the correctly spelt letters.

All the words are 3 letters long, hense the "(incompleteLetters / 3)"

Here is a fiddle to help http://jsfiddle.net/smilburn/Dxxmh/34/

Comment: Warning: there's sound in the jsfiddle, so make sure your speakers aren't set on as high volume as mine was!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only ever one *wrong* answer indicated on the board by the table cells with the class `.wordglow4`, unlike the *correct* answers which maintain the `.wordglow2` class after they have been guessed correctly.

So the count of `.wordglow2` will always be correct, whereas the count of `.wordglow4` will only ever be 3.

You should move the **count** variable outside of the `.click()` event and increment it when a word is guessed incorrectly.

So, in your example code, add...

```
var animation = false;
var incompleteWords = 0; // <-- this line
$('.drag').on('click', function(e) {
```

and change

```
var incompleteWords = (incompleteLetters / 3);
```

to

```
incompleteWords += (incompleteLetters / 3);
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I don't suppose you could help me with another problem I am having. Basically this method will only work for 3 letter words. How would I change it to work with bigger words 4-6 letters? @andyb

Comment: firstly, you'd need to change the 'correct words' counter to work the same as the incomplete words counter above.  You'd also have to change your detection code to check only the current word (ie not search for all '.wordglow2' entries on the page), and restructure your logic so you no longer need to know how many letters in each word (ie get rid of the 'completeLetters/3' stuff)

Comment: @logicalChimp has described a good approach to making it work with a variable number of letters

Answer (score 2):

the 'complete words' counter works because you always leave the '.wordglow2' style on the table cells when the word is completed.  Therefor *$('.wordglow2').length* will always return the total completed letters (and hence words)

However, the incorrect words won't work, because as soon as the user gets it right, the style is changed (from '.wordglow4' to '.wordglow2' - p.s. you might want to think about using more descriptive class names - e.g. '.correctLetter' and '.wrongLetter').  Thus, you'll never have more than 3 '.wordglow4' letters on screen, so the *incompleteWords* counter will never get past 1.

To make the incorrect word counter work, you'll need to declare the counter outside the function, and do something like:

```
var incompleteLetters = $('.wordglow4').length;
incompleteWords += (incompleteLetters / 3);
```

This should then keep track of previous failures, and give you the behaviour you want

Comment: Totally agree
"$(this).removeClass('wordglow4')" seem to be your issue should be a counter rather than "counting number of times the class exists".

Comment: +1 Was about to post the same answer. `incompleteWords` needs to be declared outside of the `.click()` and just incremented inside.

Comment: I still can't get it working. Any chance you could update my question or provide a fiddle? @logical Chimp

Comment: I still can't get it working. Any chance you could update my question or provide a fiddle? @andyb

Comment: @m0onio added my answer back with the relevant code alterations